# using the gprof -f option in Linux for c++

Tags: c++, linux, gprof

Hi so i have started using gprof for my profiling work and it works fine except for the -f option which allows me to specifiy a particular function to be viewed in the call graph.

for example

```
                 Call graph (explanation follows)


granularity: each sample hit covers 4 byte(s) no time propagated

index % time    self  children    called     name
                0.00    0.00       1/1           __do_global_ctors_aux [13]
[5]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         global constructors keyed to main [5]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) [6]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           global constructors keyed to main [5]
[6]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) [6]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [4]
[7]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         car::DisplayPrice() [7]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [4]
[8]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         car::showc() [8]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [4]
[9]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         car::car(std::string, int) [9]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           vehical::vehical(int, int) [12]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [4]
[10]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         car::~car() [10]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [4]
[11]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         vehical::show() [11]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           car::car(std::string, int) [9]
[12]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         vehical::vehical(int, int) [12]
-----------------------------------------------
```

Now if i specify

```
gprof -f car::car(std::string, int) a.out gmon.out
```

i get error

> syntax error near unexpected token '('

now if i do

gprof -f car::car(std::string, int) a.out gmon.out

i get an error

> No such file or directory

if i try putting the function in double quotes i get an output as above with no change..

CAN Someone please help me with this ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: you probably just need a pair of `"` or `'` around car::car(std::string, int). With that space between `,` and `int)` it is recognized as two different arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

() is taken by your shell. Try like this:

```
gprof -f 'car::car(std::string, int)' a.out gmon.out
```

Comment: i have tried this with ' and " but i get the same result i.e i get all the functions related to the code,while i just want the profiling info related to the function car::car(std::string, int)